# How to emit an epic only if another epic finished?

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have 2 entities: Payee and Transaction. I have `payeeCreateEpic` that filters on `started` emits the regular chain of `finished`/`failed`. The same for `transactionCreateEpic`.

For the sake of simplicity lets assume Payee have only UUID and Name. Transaction however can have one of 3 possibilities: Not attached to any payee (payload has `payee: null`), attached to existing payee (on the UI the user has a dropdown of all payees where he selects one, the payload that has `payee: payee-uuid`) or attached to a **non** existing payee (on the UI the user has the option to create  payee which is not saved to backend, but should be saved if the whole transaction is saved, in payload I send `payee: payee-name`).

Now if create transaction is submitted with no payee or existing payee, I just go to `POST /transactions` and wait for it to resolve in order to emit `finished` or `failed` action of the `transactionCreateEpic`.

However if `!isUuid(txPayload.payee)` evaluates to true, inside the epic of `transactionCreateEpic` I want to initiate the `payeeCreateEpic` with the payee name, and wait for `finished` => then create the transaction with the payee-id from the backend, or `failed` => abort the transaction (and show an error for the user).

I'm not sure how to do it, since in the transaction epic, I'm already inside filter for `TRANSACTION_CREATE_STARTED` action and not sure how I can subscribe to another action emitted by the `payeeCreateEpic`.

Some code:

```
const createPayeeEpic = (actions$: Observable<Action>) =>
    actions$.pipe(
        filter(CreateAction.start.match),
        mergeMap((action) =>
            from(MoneyPinApiClient.getInstance().payee.create(CreateRequestAdapter(action.payload))).pipe(
                map((response) => CreateAction.success({
                    params: action.payload,
                    result: CreateResultAdapter(response.data)
                })),
                catchError((err) => of(
                    <any>CreateAction.failure({params: action.payload, error: err}),
                    <any>MoneyPinApiErrorAction(err)
                ))
            )
        )
    );
const createTransactionEpic = (actions$: Observable<Action>) =>
    actions$.pipe(
        filter(CreateAction.start.match),
        mergeMap((action) => {
            if(!isUuid(action.payload.payee) {
               **EMIT PayeeCreateAction.start({name: action.payload.payee})**
               **WAIT FOR PayeeCreateAction.success (or PayeeCreateAction.failure)**
               action.payload.payee = resultOf(PayeeCreateAction.success).id;
            }
            return from(MoneyPinApiClient.getInstance().transaction.create(CreateRequestAdapter(action.payload))).pipe(
                map((response) => CreateAction.success({
                        params: action.payload,
                        result: CreateResultAdapter(response.data)
                    })),
                catchError((err) => of(
                    <any>CreateAction.failure({params: action.payload, error: err}),
                    <any>MoneyPinApiErrorAction(err)
                ))
            )
        })
    );
```

Look at the `createTransactionEpic`, this is where I'm having difficulty to actually initiate the createPayeeEpic + wait for success of failure.

Comment: Can you make an example of what you're trying to do (on StackBlitz ideally)?

Comment: @martin Edited the question with code example

Comment: What version of redux-observable are you using?

Comment: @Whymarrh ```"redux-observable": "^1.0.0"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to extract the actual create of the transaction to some factory method:

```
const transactionCreateStreamFactory = (action: MoneyPinAction<CreateActionParams>) =>
from(MoneyPinApiClient.getInstance().transaction.create(CreateRequestAdapter(action.payload))).pipe(
    concatMap((response) => CreateAction.success({
        params: action.payload,
        result: CreateResultAdapter(response.data)
    })),
    catchError((err) => of(
        <any>CreateAction.failure({params: action.payload, error: err}),
        <any>MoneyPinApiErrorAction(err)
    ))
);
```

And then the create transaction epic actually looks like this:

```
const createTransactionEpic = (actions$: Observable<Action>) =>
actions$.pipe(
    filter(CreateAction.start.match),
    mergeMap((action) => {
        const {payee, payload} = action.payload;
        if (payee && payload.payee_id) {
            return merge(
                actions$.pipe(
                    filter(PayeeCreateAction.success.match),
                    filter((payeeResponse) => payeeResponse.payload.result.payee.id === payload.payee_id),
                    take(1),
                    mergeMap(() => transactionCreateStreamFactory(action)),
                ),
                actions$.pipe(
                    filter(PayeeCreateAction.failure.match),
                    filter((payeeResponse) => payeeResponse.payload.params.payload.id === payload.payee_id),
                    take(1),
                    map(() => CreateAction.failure({
                        params: action.payload,
                        error: new Error("failed to create payee")
                    }))
                )
            ).pipe(
                startWith(PayeeCreateAction.start({
                    notebook_id: action.payload.notebook_id,
                    payload: {id: payload.payee_id, name: payee}
                }))
            );
        } else {
            return transactionCreateStreamFactory(action);
        }
    })
);
```

So if payee with id were given during the creation, I'd start another pipe, which listens to the `payee.success` or `payee.failure` action, filters the relevant action (in case multiple action of this type might come during concurrent create or whatever), listens only one time (`take(1)`), and mergeMaps this to the actual create transaction epic, and the whole stream starts with `payee.start` action that is handled by the payee epic (and it turns emits the success / failure of payee actions).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like thread synchronization one. 
Use one of thread synchronization patterns.
E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)